# TCPDF - How to adjust height of header?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to convert html to pdf format.  I am passing a string into the php script to be set as my header. I am having a hard time setting the height of my header.  I have tried using `SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 0, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT)` and `SetHeaderMargin(0)`. What it did was to only take off the top margin. I have also alternately looked into adjusting the height of the cell which contains the string within the header.

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $newHeaderString, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
```

No luck eliminating white space here either.

I have included an image to show what white space I want to eliminate.  The white space is between the header text and the hr tag from the html. Any help would be appreciated!

[Link to image](http://i51.tinypic.com/358atkk.png)

Answer (score 16):

You could define the `PDF_MARGIN_TOP` constant or you could set the margin explicitly:

```
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, but solved it by setting the margins with

```
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP-15, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
```

and

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM-15);
```

so I didn't have to change a defined constant.

Answer (score 7):

The header itself does not have a height. What you actually want to do is to change the top margin of the main "container". Look in TCPDF config file for:

```
define ('PDF_MARGIN_TOP', 19);
```

Changing the value should solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of why - that helped much more than just the answer